# Apache Spark update a row in an RDD or Dataset based on another row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to figure how I can update some rows based on another another row.

For example, I have some data like

```
Id | useraname | ratings | city
--------------------------------
1, philip, 2.0, montreal, ...
2, john, 4.0, montreal, ...
3, charles, 2.0, texas, ...
```

I want to update the users in the same city to the same groupId (either 1 or 2)

```
Id | useraname | ratings | city
--------------------------------
1, philip, 2.0, montreal, ...
1, john, 4.0, montreal, ...
3, charles, 2.0, texas, ...
```

How can I achieve this in my RDD or Dataset ?

So just for sake of completeness, what if the `Id` is a String, the dense rank won't work ?

For example ?

```
Id | useraname | ratings | city
--------------------------------
a, philip, 2.0, montreal, ...
b, john, 4.0, montreal, ...
c, charles, 2.0, texas, ...
```

So the result looks like this:

```
grade | useraname | ratings | city
--------------------------------
a, philip, 2.0, montreal, ...
a, john, 4.0, montreal, ...
c, charles, 2.0, texas, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to do this would be to use `dense_rank()` from `Window` functions. It enumerates the unique values in your `Window` column. Because `city` is a `String` column, these will be increasing alphabetically.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "philip", 2.0, "montreal"),
  (2, "john", 4.0, "montreal"),
  (3, "charles", 2.0, "texas"))).toDF("Id", "username", "rating", "city")

val w = Window.orderBy($"city")
df.withColumn("id", rank().over(w)).show()

+---+--------+------+--------+
| id|username|rating|    city|
+---+--------+------+--------+
|  1|  philip|   2.0|montreal|
|  1|    john|   4.0|montreal|
|  2| charles|   2.0|   texas|
+---+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not distributed but probably OK here so upvote.

Comment: @mtoto Thanks for the solution, but just to ask what if the `id` is a String, the dense rank won't work ?

Comment: The existing `id` column is not considered in this approach, it is merely giving unique keys to each unique value of the `city` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.select("city").distinct.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id).join(df.drop("id"), Seq("city"))
```