# How to take the top percentage from a relatively large Spark dataframe and save it to a file

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a Spark program which calculates a probability for each user which results in a relatively large dataframe (~137.5M rows). What I need to do is take the top 10% (10 is arbitrary and can be changed of course) of these users and save them to file.

A minimized example would be:

- Given this dataframe: `hc.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(("uid1", "0.5"), ("uid2", "0.7"), ("uid3", "0.3"))).toDF("uuid", "prob")`
- And given a threshold of 0.3
- I want the output to be ("uid2", "0.7") and saved into a file "output" since "uid2" has the highest prob and I only need to take the top 0.3% of the users from the dataframe

And so my question is: what would be a clean and efficient way to do this with a relatively large dataframe?

Its possible to calculate how many users is 10% of the input dataframe and then use top with the size. However I have 2 concerns regarding this:

1. When using top - is the data first being reduced before the shuffle by taking the top 10% from each executor and then take the 10% out of the shuffled data? If not, is there a built-in way to do what I suggested? Or should I just implement it myself?
2. Top returns an array which is still quite large... What I would prefer to do is keep it as a dataframe and just save its output (maybe repartition the data after the shuffle). Is there any way to do this without converting it to array and then parallelizing it?

I dont mind using RDDs instead of dataframes if needed

I'm currently using Spark 1.6.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it is probably possible using window functions, but please illustrate your question with an example dataset and expected output.

Comment: @mtoto I added a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve. Could you elaborate on the window functions?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40048439/4964651), but if you are not looking for top rows *by group* you won't be able to parallelize the operation.

Comment: First question. This will be for groups? The top 10% of groups or the top 10% of RDD?

Comment: How about doing a sort in descending order and then limit?

Comment: top 10% of RDD not of groups

Answer (score 9):

You can use the window function `percent_rank()`. However, because you are not ranking by group, you won't be able to parallelize the operation using `partitionBy()`. Here's an example in `pySpark` :

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import percent_rank, col

window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(df['prob'].desc())

df.select('*', percent_rank().over(window).alias('rank')) 
  .filter(col('rank') <= 0.3) # top 30% for example
  .show() 
+----+----+----+
|uuid|prob|rank|
+----+----+----+
|uid2| 0.7| 0.0|
+----+----+----+
```

**Data:**

```
df = sc.parallelize([("uid1", "0.5"), 
                     ("uid2", "0.7"), 
                     ("uid3", "0.3")]).toDF(["uuid", "prob"])
```